# Matlab cconv and circular convolution

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

My goal is to use Matlab to verify circular convolution calculations. I try to do this using [cconv](http://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cconv.html).

**However, Matlab does not give the same answer to problems I know the answer for. Why?**

An example is the circular convolution modulo 4 between [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and [7, 8, 9, 3] as can be found in [this paper by Abassi](http://12000.org/my_notes/circular_convolution/circonv_long.pdf)

According to the paper the answer is: [112, 91, 71, 88, 124].

But according to Matlab it is: [131, 127, 122, 106].

```
a = [1,2,4,5,6]
b = [7,8,9,3]
y = cconv(a,b,4)
ans =

   131   127   122   106
```

**What do I do wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
y = cconv(a,b,5)
```

the 3rd argument is 5 not 4 for what the paper describes

Comment: Stupid me used the wrong argument:p Sry, and thank you for your time:)

Comment: Obviously, I need to re-read up on circular convolution.  Thanks for the correction.  It has been a while.

Answer (score 0):

The matlab code used in the [Abbasi](http://12000.org/my_notes/circular_convolution/circonv_long.pdf) paper is written in the end :

```
A=fft(a);
B=fft(b);
y=ifft(A.*B);
```

I don't know why you use cconv if this doese the work.

Comment: Probably for proof of concept.  Besides which, the accepted answer tells you how to get the answers to match.